# How to fix 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (FairPlayErrorDomain error -42022.)' , when I call [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment]

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

A user gave feedback that it could not be purchased by apple iap, and we found the error message was:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (FairPlayErrorDomain error -42022.)
```

The user device system version is iOS 8.1.2

I searched the Internet and couldn't find a relevant solution.
According to the log, after this method is called

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment: payment];
```

In this callback

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

transaction.transactionState:
SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed

transaction.error.localizedDescription:
The operation couldn’t be completed. (FairPlayErrorDomain error -42022.)

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to be able to pay successfully

Comment: I would start by asking them to upgrade their iOS. Even if they can't go to iOS 9 they can go to 8.4.1

Comment: I am facing the same problem in ios 8.1. Is there any alternate solution rather than upgrading iOS